# Should I be worried about too much lines in TextWidget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program using Python and Tkinter. In it I have a text widget which holds text which might be described as "protocol" of what is going on in the program. User can clear it in program but I am worried that this text might get too big. Is there some upper limit for a number of lines in text widget ? Or is there some other reason coonnected with number of lines in text widget because of which program may crash ? If so, is there some way to estimate this upper bound so that I can check how many lines are there in text widget anytime I add text to it ?

Comment: It would be easy to write a small program that adds several tens of thousands of lines of text to see how well it handles it. Have you tried that?

Comment: There's no simple answer to this because it depends heavily on the environment in which the code is running (hardware and OS). I don't think for practical purposes there's any software limits, just differences in speed when scrolling the text or resizing the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh, I haven't thought of that. Now I tried and it seems ok for at least a million lines and it is enough for me. Thanks.